# Como fazer com que o "$(window).scroll" execute apenas uma vez?

Tags: jquery, rolamento, jquery-animate

Quando realizo o scroll, a função executa normalmente, mas fica repetindo toda vez que continuo com o scroll do mouse. Gostaria de saber como fazê-la executar somente uma vez.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {  
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop >= 100) {     
        $("#box").animate(
           { margin:'50px 0 0 0' },
            600
        ); // end animate
    }
});
```

Comment: Tente trocar `$(window).scroll(function () {  ` por `$(window).on('scroll',function () {  `

Comment: Assim a função executa e volta ao seu estado inicial. Por exemplo, faz o marginTop 50px e retorna ao 0. Preciso que ela vá até o 50px e fique no 50.

Comment: Na verdade era `on` e não `one`.

Comment: mesmo com 'on', não resolveu

Comment: Poste seu código completo no [jsfilder](https://jsfiddle.net/) para ficar mais fácil de vermos o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um `flag` qualquer e altere seu valor quando entrar no `if`. Assim, só entrará uma vez:

```
var flag = true;
$(window).scroll(function () {  

   var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();        


   if (scrollTop >= 100 && flag) {    

      flag = false;         

      $("#box").animate({
         margin:'50px 0 0 0'
      },600);//end animate        
   }

});//
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var flag = true;
$(window).scroll(function () {  

   var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();        


   if (scrollTop >= 100 && flag) {    
      console.log("Só vai executar 1 vez");
      flag = false;         

      $("#box").animate({
         margin:'50px 0 0 0'
      },600);//end animate        
   }

});//
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="position: fixed;">
   div
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Aconteceu da mesma forma, a função executa e volta ao seu estado inicial. Por exemplo, faz o marginTop 50px e retorna ao 0. Preciso que ela vá até o 50px e fique no 50

Comment: Creio que não, execute o exemplo que coloquei na resposta agora.

Comment: feito, resolvido